# Cannot draw line and rectangle on the canvas at the same time

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, angular9

I have created the button for drawing **Line, Pencil, Rectangle** and they are working fine but when I draw a line after drawing a rectangle then it **clears my canvas entirely**. As I've tried everything.
My code is in Angular 9. I want to apply this in canvas HTML.
First I want to draw say Line and then a rectangle so it should show both rather than clear the canvas.

```html
<div class="field">
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    <div class="tools" style="margin-top: 20px;">
      <button type="button" (click)="createLines()">Line</button>
      <button type="button" (click)="createPencil()">Pencil</button>
      <button type="button" (click)="createRectangle()">Rectangle</button>
      <div (click)="change_color_red()" class="color-field" style="background-color: red;"></div>
      <div (click)="change_color_blue()" class="color-field" style="background-color: blue;"></div>
      <div (click)="change_color_green()" class="color-field" style="background-color: green;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
HTML
```

```js
@ViewChild('canvas', {static: false}) canvas: ElementRef;

createPencil(){
  this.mode = "Pencil";
  this.createLine();
}
createLines(){
  this.mode = "Line";
  this.createLine();
}
createRectangle(){
  this.mode = "Rectangle";
  this.createLine();
}
createLine(){
  const canvasEle = <HTMLCanvasElement> document.querySelector('#canvas');
  const context = canvasEle.getContext("2d");
  canvasEle.height = window.innerHeight-500;
  canvasEle.width = window.innerWidth-500;
  let startPosition = {x: 0, y: 0};
  let lineCoordinates = {x: 0, y: 0};
  let isDrawStart = false;
  this.draw_color = "black";

  const getClientOffset = (event) => {
      const {pageX, pageY} = event.touches ? event.touches[0] : event;
      const x = pageX - canvasEle.offsetLeft;
      const y = pageY - canvasEle.offsetTop;

      return {
        x,
        y
      } 
  }
  const drawRectangle = (e) => {
    context.beginPath();
    context.lineWidth=2;
    context.rect(startPosition.x, startPosition.y,lineCoordinates.x, lineCoordinates.y);
    context.strokeStyle = this.draw_color;
    context.stroke();
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  function drawPencil(e){
    context.lineWidth = 2;
    context.lineCap = "round";
    context.moveTo(e.X,e.Y);
    context.lineTo(e.clientX- canvasEle.offsetLeft, e.clientY- canvasEle.offsetTop);
    context.stroke();
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  const drawLine = (e) => {
    context.beginPath();
    context.lineWidth=2;
    context.moveTo(startPosition.x, startPosition.y);
    context.lineTo(lineCoordinates.x, lineCoordinates.y);
    context.fillRect=this.draw_color;
    context.stroke();
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  const mouseDownListener = (event) => {
    startPosition = getClientOffset(event);
    isDrawStart = true;
    takesnapshot();
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  const mouseMoveListener = (event) => {
    if(!isDrawStart) return;
    if(this.mode == 'Line'){
      restoresnapshot();
      lineCoordinates = getClientOffset(event);
      drawLine(event);
    }else if(this.mode == 'Rectangle'){
      restoresnapshot();
      lineCoordinates = getClientOffset(event);
      drawRectangle(event);
    }else{
      restoresnapshot();
      lineCoordinates = getClientOffset(event);
      drawPencil(event);
    }
   
  }

  const mouseupListener = (event) => {
    isDrawStart = false;
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  const takesnapshot = () => {
    this.snapshot = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvasEle.width, canvasEle.height);
  }

  const restoresnapshot = () => {
    context.putImageData(this.snapshot,0, 0);
  }

  canvasEle.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDownListener);
  canvasEle.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoveListener);
  canvasEle.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseupListener);
}
change_color_red(){
  this.draw_color = "red";
}
change_color_blue(){
  this.draw_color = "blue";
}
change_color_green(){
  this.draw_color = "green";
}
```

Comment: Setting the canvas width or height attribute clears the current image. You do both in the `createLine()` function. Consider putting those 2 lines near the point at which you add the event listeners.

Comment: It worked. First I placed the canvas width and height near event listners, it didn't work. Then I put the code in ngonit() now its's working fine. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Okay, so run the debuger step by step and see which line does it. Ctrl-Shift-I brings it up, you'll want to set a break-point inside the start of the code that handles the bit that works wrong. E.g inside the mousedown or mouseup handlers.